Updating Stripe NAME field does nothing when exporting transactions as IIF file
I'm exporting Stripe transactions to QuickBooks via an IIF file. However, I'm facing an issue where the NAME field in the export contains outdated information, even though I've updated the NAME in Stripe to reflect what QuickBooks expects.
Here's what I've tried:
Updated the NAME field in Stripe under the relevant customer/transaction.
Re-exported the transactions as an IIF file after making the updates.

Despite these changes, the exported IIF file still contains the old NAME, and the new information is not reflected in the export.
Has anyone encountered this issue before? What might I be missing or overlooking to ensure the updated NAME is included in the IIF file?
Any help or guidance would be appreciated!
